# Google Script Editor - Import multiple Csv files as multiple spreadsheets

Tags: csv, import, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 90 csv files in my Google Drive Id like to import into 90 distinct Google spreadsheets.

I used [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2) to import 1 csv to 1 spreadsheet, but would it be possible to script import for my 90 files ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can loop the same code for all files.

1. You have to make changes in this following line:

   function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
       // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
       var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();

to get the range of each sheet by name.

2. Also save the filenames for the csv files and loop through them.

Hope that helps!